# stored procedure to find the day from IN parameter date

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

please help me to find the passing IN parameter that give the day is Monday or else an weekday.
give the working code for this stored procedure.

like as an example-

call check_date(1982-01-10);

gives -weekday.

Comment: What stored procedure are you talking about? How do we guess? More information needed

Comment: Did you even try something ?

Comment: here pass the IN parameter as date ,and it will return monday else weekday .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE PROCEDURE p2(dt  datetime )
BEGIN

select DAYNAME(dt);

END

run procedure with below command :

call p2('2015-08-05')

Result  : wednesday

you have to pass '1982-01-10' into p2 function just like below :
call p2('1982-01-10');

it gives output as -weekday.

Comment: this is perfect answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach;

```
CALL FindDate("'Sunday','Monday,'Friday','Saturday'")
```

and this stored procedure;

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE FindDate(IN p_type VARCHAR(65535))
    BEGIN
        SET @query = CONCAT ('Select date from X WHERE Date  IN (',p_type,')');
         EXECUTE @query
     END
```

Answer (score 0):

select DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE());

select DAYNAME('2015-08-05');

you can use dayname function to find out dayname for particular date.

Comment: how can we use into an stored procedure.as the date as IN parameter ?